# Get current URL with PHP and change a part of it for a new url

Tags: php, wordpress, url, elementor

I am working on a WordPress website for a client. I want to create a switch element through a current URL change.
For instance;

https://mywebsite.com/shop/CUSTOMER
should change to
https://mywebsite.com/shop/OWNER

```
  echo $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

I have found a php code that provides me the URL of the current page. So if the visitor is on the /shop/customer page, I've found a way to create a shortcode and add my own string to it. But it creates a new link like; /shop/customer/owner

I want to replace customer in owner, not adding owner to the current link. Because it has to be a dynamic solution. For example, if the visitor is on https://mywebsite.com/shoppingcart/customer, they should change this to https://mywebsite.com/shoppingcart/owner

Sorry for the bad english, hope you understand what i need.

Regards,
Rick

Comment: Do you just want the URL to be different, but the content will be the same? Or can redirects help you? I'm not clear on what exactly you are attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this could work!

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$change_url = str_replace("customer","shopping",$actual_link);
echo $change_url;
```